# Wrapping h5 in Link tag made h5 dissappear

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to make a component go to localhost:3000/second. The header for the component(AddNote) displays when I dont wrap it in a Link tag, but when I do, the whole page becomes blank, including the "My Notes" which is supposed to be displayed by default.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import AddNote from './components/noteDisplay/addNote/newNote.js'
import FirstPage from './components/noteDisplay/firstPage.js'
import NoteDisplay from './components/noteDisplay/noteDisplay.js'
import secondPage from './components/secondPage/secondContainer.js'
const App = () => {

  return (
      
        <div className="App">
          
          <h1 className="app-title">My notes</h1>
          
          <Router>
            <div>
              <Routes>

                <Route path='/second' element={<secondPage />}/>
                {/*<Route path='/' element={<NoteDisplay/>}/>*/}

              </Routes>
              
            </div>

          </Router>
          <AddNote/>
          
        </div> 
        


  );
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import NoteDisplay from '../noteDisplay';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';


const AddNote = () => {
    console.log('hi')
    return (
        <div>
            <Link to="/second">
                <h5 className="add-note">New note</h5>
            </Link>  
        </div>
        



    )

}
export default AddNote;
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how to follow up when folks answer your questions. I see that you've posted many questions without giving credit where it's due.

Comment: And if you don't intend to resolve this post, delete it. Abandoned posts are ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `<Link />` code to be something like below.

```js
const AddNote = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h5>
        <Link href="/second">New Note</Link>
      </h5>
    </div>
  );
};
```

See the official [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) for how to use it - it explains it in greater detail!